# How do i use the less than or greater than signs inside html in python django

Tags: python, html, django, filefield

Hi am struggling using the greater than sign inside the html template. am using python 3.7.2 and django 1.8.6 
I cant execute this code here gives an error

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block Content %}
<h1>Tags</h1>
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <li><a href='{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ instance.title }}</a> ({{ instance.products.count }} product{% if instance.products.count > 1 %}s{% endif %})</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No Tags yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

So the > 1 is the problem here 
help out

Comment: What error does it give you? The syntax itself should work.

Comment: actually works fine on the page but inside atom all the elements inside {{ }} are red and it is not usual